# python requests module find urls within the urls already found

Tags: python, python-requests

This script returns a list of URLs found on the web page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment

with requests.session() as r:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'}
    r = requests.get('https://ctflearn.com', verify=False, headers=headers)
    response = r.text
    soup = BS(response, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup.find_all('a')

    for tag in tags:
        links = tag.get('href')
        if links[0] == '/':
            appended_link = 'https://ctflearn.com' + links
            print(appended_link)
        elif links[0] == '#':
            pass
        else:
            print(links)
```

However, what I am interested in is to visit these web pages and find the links within these pages as well. I know it is possible by using a for loop, but I don't know how to implement it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store found links, and whether or not you have visited them or not. E.g. `{ "https://some.url/": True }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply try to use two lists (`to_visit` and `visited`) with a check if a url is already in one of those lists before you add it to `to_visit`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4 import Comment

with requests.session() as r:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'}
    to_visit = ['https://ctflearn.com']
    visited = []

    while (len(to_visit) > 0):
        url = to_visit.pop(0)
        visited.append(url)

        print('visited: "{0}"'.format(url))

        r = requests.get(url, verify=True, headers=headers)
        response = r.text
        soup = BS(response, 'html.parser')
        tags = soup.find_all('a')

        for tag in tags:
            links = tag.get('href')
            if links == None:
                continue
            elif links[0] == '/':
                appended_link = 'https://ctflearn.com' + links
                if (appended_link not in visited and appended_link not in to_visit):
                    to_visit.append(appended_link)
            elif links[0] == '#':
                pass
            else:
                if (links not in visited and links not in to_visit):
                    to_visit.append(links)
```

but at some point you will run into a problem because you will find and try to access something that is not an url which is why I would recommend using a validator:

```
import validators 

validators.url(url) # returns True if "url" is a valid url
```